# Can i create an image from an excel file using c#

Tags: c#, image, excel, openxml

Is there a way to take an image of an excel file without using office.interop dlls ? 
I succeeded to embed an excel file into a word document, but i need to show an image of this excel file on the word document. Using filestream, i can read any image and embed into the word document using open xml. The last thing who rest is creating an image from an excel file.

Comment: Is it XLS or XLSX? For XLSX you can easily use OpenXML SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpreadsheetGear 2012 for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com) can do that:

```
using SpreadsheetGear;
...
// Open workbook (SpreadsheetGear supports both XLS and XLSX/XLSM file formats)
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook(@"C:\path\to\workbook.xlsx");
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

// Create Image class, passing in desired range to render 
SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Image image = new SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Image(worksheet.Cells["A1:D10"]);

// Create Bitmap of range
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = image.GetBitmap();

// ... Insert into Word ...
```

The Image class also accepts [`IShape`](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Shapes.IShape.html) and [`IChart`](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Charts.IChart.html) objects if you wish to render images of those objects instead.  Once you have a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` you can presumably do whatever you want with it, including inserting into a Word document.  You can find additional samples on the [Excel Chart and Range Imaging Samples](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/imaging.aspx) page.

Disclaimer: I work for SpreadsheetGear.